# IBM Datastage reports failure code 262148

Tags: datastage, information-server

I realize this is a bad question, but I don't know where else to turn.

can someone point me to where I can find the list of reports failure codes for IBM?  I've tried searching for it in the IBM documentation, and in general google search, but this particular error is unique and I've never seen it before.

I'm trying to find out what code 262148 means.

Background:
I built a datastage job that has:

```
ORACLE CONNECTOR --> TRANSFORMER -> HIERARCHICAL DATA
```

The intent is to pull data from a ORACLE table, and output the response of the select statement into a JSON file.  I'm using the HIERARCHICAL stage to set it.  When tested in the stage, no problems, I see the JSON output.

However, when I run the job, it squawks:

```
reports failure code 262148
```

then the job aborts.  There are no warnings, no signs, no errors prior to this line.

Until I know what it is, I can't troubleshoot.

If someone can point me to where the list of failure codes are, i can proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more context - where did you see this error? Any additional message? What did you do?

Comment: Strange failure code - I suggest to open a ticket with IBM support

Comment: I tried.  but as you can imagine, it'll take a long time.  So to that end, I'm still trying here.  Thanks tho.

Comment: What DataStage version are you using ?

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm using 11.5.  Thanks

Comment: @arcee123 Did you think like => `262148 = 0x40004` ?

Comment: Hi @Antonio ... can you explain?  what is 0x40004?

Comment: @arcee123 Haha... It was just my guessing. But it seems like it will be better to find this error in the Heximal type. Good luck!!!

Comment: @arcee123 Actually, i googled alot to find that error, but there were only decimal 40004 errors.

Answer (score 0):

> can someone point me to where I can find the list of reports failure codes for IBM?

Here you go:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahb/rzahbsrclist.htm

While this list does not list your specific error code, it does categorize many other codes, and explains how the code breakdown works. While this list is not specifically for DataStage, in my experience IBM standards are *generally* compatible across different products. In this list *every* code that starts with a 2 is a disk failure, so maybe run a disk checker. That's the best I've got as far as error codes.

Without knowledge of the inner workings of the product, there is not much more you can do beyond checking system health in general (especially disk, network and permissions in this case). Personally, I prefer to go get internal knowledge whenever exterior knowledge proves insufficient. I would start with a network capture, as I'm sure there's a socket involved in the connection between the layers. Compare the network capture from when the select statement is run from the hierarchical from one captured when run from the job. There may be clues in there, like reset or refused connections.